# Django POST 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, post, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to post a message with javascript on a 1.11 django wannabe chat server. I'm rather new to javascript and so I'm posting and getting is rather new to me. If I create a message in the database it appears in the chat box. This makes me believe that this is just a posting error. This is the following error I'm getting:

```
chat.js:13 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/api/messages/ 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
r.(anonymous function) @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
send @ chat.js:13
(anonymous) @ (index):186
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

project's urls.py

```
url(r'^chat/', include("chat.urls",namespace='chat')),
```

chat's urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', chat_view, name='chats'),
    url(r'^(?P<sender>\d+)/(?P<receiver>\d+)/$', message_view, name='chat'),
    url(r'^api/messages/(?P<sender>\d+)/(?P<receiver>\d+)/$', message_list, name='message-detail'),
    url(r'^api/messages/$', message_list, name='message-list'),
    url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', user_list, name='user-detail'),
    url(r'^api/users/$', user_list, name='user-list'),
    ]
```

java script:

```
//For sending
    $(function () {
        scrolltoend();
        $('#chat-box').on('submit', function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            event.preventDefault();
            var message = $('#id_message');
            send('{{ request.user.username }}', '{{ receiver.username }}', message.val());
            message.val('');
        })
    })
```

more js

```
function send(sender, receiver, message) {
    $.post('/chat/api/messages/', '{"sender": "'+ sender +'", "receiver": "'+ receiver +'","message": "'+ message +'" }', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var box = text_box.replace('{sender}', "You");
        box = box.replace('{message}', message);
        $('#board').append(box);
        scrolltoend();
    })
}

function receive() {
    $.get('/chat/api/messages/'+ sender_id + '/' + receiver_id, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.length !== 0)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                console.log(data[i]);
                var box = text_box.replace('{sender}', data[i].sender);
                box = box.replace('{message}', data[i].message);
                box = box.replace('right', 'left blue lighten-5');
                $('#board').append(box);
                scrolltoend();
            }
        }
    })
}

function scrolltoend() {
$('#board').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $('#board')[0].scrollHeight
}, 800);
}
```

Thoughts on what is wrong

Comment: If you look in your browsers dev tools is there an error message in the response?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/api/messages/ 400 (Bad Request) This is the error message I see in the console tab (first greyed out area above).